# IIS7 rewrite regular expression does not identifying + sign

Tags: php, iis-7, web-config

I am using PHP with IIS7. In web.config file i have made rewrite rule. 
Pattern which i am matching is

```
^product/([0-9a-zA-Z\+\-]+)$
```

Now the problem is it does not work when there are + sign in url for example it does not work for

```
http://mywebsite/product/ABC+DEF+GHI
```

I need it to work for above.

But it does work for

```
http://mywebsite/product/ABC DEF GHI
```

So i guess it is identifying  space but not +

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found answer. Just sharing in case anybody needs.

Just put

```
<system.webServer>
<security>
    <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true"/>
</security>
```

in web.config file.

And Done